# The Ship Dedicated Server - Sourcemod causing random crashes

Tags: linux, source-engine, server-administration

I'm no stranger to Linux server administration, but I'd probably still consider myself an amateur compared to some of the very skilled out there. I'm familiar with TF2 server administration to a fair extent, and have been doing so on our community's server for a couple of years now, and I'm familiar with the newer stuff since the switch from hlds to srcds, though I don't think the latter applies to The Ship.

Anyhow, we recently got into The Ship, and I decided to throw a server up since there's only one server with users seemingly, and it lags and isn't even on Hunt.

Anyhoo, I downloaded the server onto my box:

```
~/hlds$ ./steam -command update -game ship -dir theship
```

a 64-bit Debian Squeeze VPS with Linode, 4GB of RAM and 4 vCPUs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux serenade 3.5.2-x86_64-linode26 #1 SMP Wed Aug 15 14:31:07 EDT 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and it wouldn't even connect to the master servers. I did some googling, and came to find that the binary that Steam supplies (~/hlds/theship/bin/engine_i686.so) does not connect to the proper master servers, and got the bytes that I needed to patch ( http://forum.i3d.net/hlds-valve-linux-newsletter/190790-hlds_linux-ship-freeze-start-server.html ) to get the server working:

```
~/hlds/theship/bin$ md5sum engine_i686.so.bak
bc45841d4e5e4a69bb105cefc8733aee  engine_i686.so.bak
~/hlds/theship/bin$ md5sum engine_i686.so
76d68eb174b108aa25c983a31e71181d  engine_i686.so
```

I did that, and the server booted up just fine. Very shortly into gameplay, a jerk came on, flaming other people and ignoring the game mode (i.e. killing everyone and having a very low amount of money; we disabled the kick for this since it really can happen accidentally, and we wanted to judge on a per-situation-basis), and after asking him to stop and him cursing at me, I decided I wanted to ban him. I did and rcon_password and an rcon, only to find the password I set for some reason didn't work (it ended up being the double quotes wrapping it that the default server.cfg provides for some reason).

Anyhow, it took around two minutes for me to get him banned, and I decided that I wanted sourcemod. I grabbed the newest metamod:source (mmsource-1.9.0-linux.tar.gz), as well as the newest stable sourcemod (sourcemod-1.4.6-linux.tar.gz), since the sourcemod wiki alleged that even the newest versions should be compatible with The Ship, since it's based on Source Engine. I have, however, also tried with the newest (at the time) dev version (sourcemod-1.5.0-hg3657-linux.tar.gz), but without any different (near as I can tell) results.

It started crashing, even with basic configurations. I'm not running any special extensions, and I had a few non-standard plugins enabled (godmode.smx rules.smx sum.smx vbping.smx), but began disabling them in an attempt to debug (disabled rules.smx sum.smx and reservedslots.smx since it was kicking humans before bots, and we have yet to have a full server).

Once I got debug working (had to install gdb), I got a few crash logs:

```
----------------------------------------------
CRASH: Mon Oct  1 04:35:19 MDT 2012
Start Line: ./srcds_i686 -console -game ship +map rubicon -maxplayers 16 -ip mpql.net -port 27016 -tickrate 100 -secure -debug
[New Thread 3518]
[New Thread 3522]
#0  0xf75e2610 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
End of Source crash report
----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------
CRASH: Mon Oct  1 10:36:48 MDT 2012
Start Line: ./srcds_i686 -console -game ship +map rubicon -maxplayers 16 -ip mpql.net -port 27016 -tickrate 100 -secure -debug
[New Thread 3923]
[New Thread 3927]
#0  0xf1eb9a58 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
End of Source crash report
----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------
CRASH: Mon Oct  1 12:25:52 MDT 2012
Start Line: ./srcds_i686 -console -game ship +map rubicon -maxplayers 16 -ip mpql.net -port 27016 -tickrate 100 -secure -debug
[New Thread 4470]
[New Thread 4471]
#0  0xf75ed610 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
End of Source crash report
----------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------
CRASH: Mon Oct  1 16:30:20 MDT 2012
Start Line: ./srcds_i686 -console -game ship +map rubicon -maxplayers 16 -ip mpql.net -port 27016 -tickrate 100 -secure -debug
[New Thread 4592]
[New Thread 4593]
#0  0xf1e50a58 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
End of Source crash report
----------------------------------------------
```

The most recent of which, generated this in the console:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
BFD: Warning: ~/hlds/theship/core is truncated: expected core file size >= 256499712, found: 1261568.
Cannot access memory at address 0xf774f8f0
Cannot access memory at address 0x484
~/hlds/theship/debug.cmds:3: Error in sourced command file:
Cannot access memory at address 0xf774f8f0
email debug.log to linux@valvesoftware.com
Mon Oct  1 16:30:20 MDT 2012: Server restart in 10 seconds[/code]And here're the
```

Here're the sourcemod logs:

```
~/hlds/theship/ship/addons/sourcemod/logs$ cat *
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:26: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:26: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:26: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:26: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:31: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 19:48:40: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 19:48:40: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:45: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:45: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:45: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:54: [sum.smx] SUM: Query failed! column steamid is not unique
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:54: [sum.smx] SUM: Query failed! column steamid is not unique
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:54: [sum.smx] SUM: Query failed! column steamid is not unique
L 09/30/2012 - 20:13:35: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 20:13:35: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:13:35: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 20:25:01: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 20:25:01: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:25:01: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:15: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:15: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:15: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:15: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:16: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:41: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:41: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:41: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:41: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:42: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:29: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:29: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:29: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:29: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:30: [sum.smx] SUM: Database failure: Could not find database conf "sumdb"
L 09/30/2012 - 21:09:09: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 21:09:09: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 21:09:09: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 22:38:14: Error log file session closed.
L 09/30/2012 - 23:56:19: SourceMod error session started
L 09/30/2012 - 23:56:19: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20120930.log")
L 09/30/2012 - 23:56:19: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 23:59:38: Error log file session closed.
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: [SM] Unable to load extension "sdktools.ext": ~/hlds/theship/ship/addons/sourcemod/extensions/sdktools.ext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: [SM] Unable to load plugin "basecomm.smx": Required extension "SDKTools" file("sdktools.ext") not running
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: [SM] Unable to load plugin "funvotes.smx": Required extension "SDKTools" file("sdktools.ext") not running
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: [SM] Unable to load plugin "funcommands.smx": Required extension "SDKTools" file("sdktools.ext") not running
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: [SM] Unable to load plugin "playercommands.smx": Required extension "SDKTools" file("sdktools.ext") not running
L 10/01/2012 - 00:35:11: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 00:35:11: Info (map "batavier") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 00:35:11: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 10/01/2012 - 00:39:34: Error log file session closed.
L 10/01/2012 - 01:09:20: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 01:09:20: Info (map "rubicon") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 01:09:20: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 10/01/2012 - 02:05:24: Error log file session closed.
L 10/01/2012 - 04:35:36: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 04:35:36: Info (map "rubicon") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 04:35:36: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 10/01/2012 - 04:41:43: Error log file session closed.
L 10/01/2012 - 10:37:10: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 10:37:10: Info (map "rubicon") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 10:37:10: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 10/01/2012 - 11:44:59: Error log file session closed.
L 10/01/2012 - 12:26:04: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 12:26:04: Info (map "rubicon") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 12:26:04: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 10/01/2012 - 13:34:15: Error log file session closed.
L 10/01/2012 - 16:30:33: SourceMod error session started
L 10/01/2012 - 16:30:33: Info (map "rubicon") (file "errors_20121001.log")
L 10/01/2012 - 16:30:33: [SDKTOOLS] Could not locate FireOutput - Disabling detour
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:26: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 09/30/2012 - 19:43:26: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 19:48:17: [basecommands.smx] "Console<0><Console><Console>" refreshed the admin cache.
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:45: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 09/30/2012 - 19:51:45: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 19:54:09: [basecommands.smx] "Console<0><Console><Console>" refreshed the admin cache.
L 09/30/2012 - 19:55:03: [basecommands.smx] "Console<0><Console><Console>" refreshed the admin cache.
L 09/30/2012 - 20:13:35: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:13:35: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 20:25:01: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:25:01: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:15: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.4.6")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:15: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:18: [UPDATER] Successfully updated gamedata file "sdktools.games/engine.ep2valve.txt"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:18: [UPDATER] Successfully updated gamedata file "sm-cstrike.games.txt"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:18: [UPDATER] Successfully updated gamedata file "sm-tf2.games.txt"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:18: [UPDATER] Successfully updated gamedata file "core.games/master.games.txt"
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:18: [UPDATER] SourceMod has been updated, please reload it or restart your server.
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:41: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.4.6")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:30:41: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:29: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.4.6")
L 09/30/2012 - 20:52:29: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 21:09:09: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.4.6")
L 09/30/2012 - 21:09:09: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 22:38:07: [SM] Changed map to "atalanta"
L 09/30/2012 - 22:38:14: -------- Mapchange to atalanta --------
L 09/30/2012 - 23:40:58: [SM] Changed map to "rubicon"
L 09/30/2012 - 23:41:07: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 09/30/2012 - 23:56:19: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20120930.log") (Version "1.4.6")
L 09/30/2012 - 23:56:19: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 09/30/2012 - 23:59:35: [basecommands.smx] "Mopsy<18><STEAM_0:0:32502293><>" changed map to "rubicon"
L 09/30/2012 - 23:59:38: [SM] Changed map to "rubicon"
L 09/30/2012 - 23:59:38: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 00:33:21: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 10/01/2012 - 00:35:11: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 00:35:11: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 10/01/2012 - 00:39:32: [SM] Changed map to "atalanta"
L 10/01/2012 - 00:39:34: -------- Mapchange to atalanta --------
L 10/01/2012 - 00:41:54: [SM] Changed map to "rubicon"
L 10/01/2012 - 00:41:54: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 00:45:44: [SM] Changed map to "andrea_doria"
L 10/01/2012 - 00:45:47: -------- Mapchange to andrea_doria --------
L 10/01/2012 - 00:49:00: [SM] Changed map to "cyclops"
L 10/01/2012 - 00:49:03: -------- Mapchange to cyclops --------
L 10/01/2012 - 01:05:40: [SM] Changed map to "cotopaxi"
L 10/01/2012 - 01:05:44: -------- Mapchange to cotopaxi --------
L 10/01/2012 - 01:09:20: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 01:09:20: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 02:05:24: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 03:13:31: [SM] Changed map to "batavier"
L 10/01/2012 - 03:13:32: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 10/01/2012 - 04:22:24: [SM] Changed map to "atalanta"
L 10/01/2012 - 04:22:25: -------- Mapchange to atalanta --------
L 10/01/2012 - 04:35:36: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 04:35:36: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 04:41:38: [basecommands.smx] "Mopsy<17><STEAM_0:0:32502293><>" changed map to "andrea_doria"
L 10/01/2012 - 04:41:41: [SM] Changed map to "andrea_doria"
L 10/01/2012 - 04:41:43: -------- Mapchange to andrea_doria --------
L 10/01/2012 - 05:50:06: [SM] Changed map to "batavier"
L 10/01/2012 - 05:50:07: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 10/01/2012 - 06:54:16: [SM] Changed map to "atalanta"
L 10/01/2012 - 06:54:17: -------- Mapchange to atalanta --------
L 10/01/2012 - 08:04:07: [SM] Changed map to "huronian"
L 10/01/2012 - 08:04:13: -------- Mapchange to huronian --------
L 10/01/2012 - 09:12:34: [SM] Changed map to "andrea_doria"
L 10/01/2012 - 09:12:35: -------- Mapchange to andrea_doria --------
L 10/01/2012 - 10:19:42: [SM] Changed map to "cyclops"
L 10/01/2012 - 10:19:46: -------- Mapchange to cyclops --------
L 10/01/2012 - 10:37:10: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 10:37:10: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 11:44:57: [SM] Changed map to "batavier"
L 10/01/2012 - 11:44:59: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 10/01/2012 - 12:26:04: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 12:26:04: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 10/01/2012 - 13:34:14: [SM] Changed map to "batavier"
L 10/01/2012 - 13:34:15: -------- Mapchange to batavier --------
L 10/01/2012 - 14:43:22: [SM] Changed map to "atalanta"
L 10/01/2012 - 14:43:23: -------- Mapchange to atalanta --------
L 10/01/2012 - 15:47:47: [SM] Changed map to "huronian"
L 10/01/2012 - 15:47:48: -------- Mapchange to huronian --------
L 10/01/2012 - 16:30:33: SourceMod log file session started (file "L20121001.log") (Version "1.5.0-dev+3657")
L 10/01/2012 - 16:30:33: -------- Mapchange to rubicon --------
L 09/30/2012 - 21:58:39: [vbping.smx] Cochise has 1 ping warning (Ping: 310.516937)
L 09/30/2012 - 22:11:59: [vbping.smx] LandLubber has 1 ping warning (Ping: 326.913452)
L 09/30/2012 - 23:18:34: [vbping.smx] Cochise has 1 ping warning (Ping: 274.923400)
```

Anyhow, if you've gotten this far, I really appreciate you reading everything, and sorry for the long post. I'm trying to be thorough so as not to upset anyone donating their time. I apologize in advance if I've left out something important, or done something incredibly stupid that might be causing this issue. Let me know if there're any tests or commands you want me to run (but be prepared to explain what they do if I don't recognize them -- I'll also be checking Google to see if it agrees with you!).

Also, I've replaced all instances of "/home/<my username>/" with simply "~" -- both sans quotes -- more paranoia than a security issue, I'm aware. Nothing of mine is outside of my home directory though, so it shouldn't affect anything.

Thanks in advance to anyone with any insight, and to anyone else who read everything. =]

P.S. I tried tagging this as the-ship, but I have less than 300 reputation, so it will not let me. I searched for other tags, but found nothing relevant.

Comment: Sadly unless somebody is familar with both programming and the mod in question this really is not on topic for this stack exchange website, since it mainly has to do with, the reason your application is crashing caused by an mod.

Comment: Personally, I'd Google some of the error lines, and see what shows up.  If that doesn't solve the problem, I'd chuck the whole thing out the window, mods and all, and add them one by one until I could reproduce the error.

Comment: Ramhound: It's THE de facto mod for administration of any server that runs on hlds or srcds, and according to their wiki, it's completely compatible with The Ship.

fbueckert: I did Google a ton for the error lines. That's what I always do when I run across errors. I've also learned that when you can't find your problem on the net, you create your own content to get responses; someone has to, or it won't be there for the Googling. Besides that, sourcemod/metamod is the only thing I have enabled. Disabling it WILL fix things, but that doesn't solve anything.

I appreciate the feedback, guys!